# SD card unreliable under Linux?

Tags: linux, sd-card, e2fsck

I am having heavy (and repeatable) problems with writing SD cards under Linux.

### Background:

- I'm working on an embedded system using an SD card for it's root fs.
- Often I see fsck errors.
- I thought we had some problem with our hardware.
- Filesystem is `ext3`.

### Problem:

Even on PC (fairly recent KUbuntu, if it matters) I see errors.
As an example:

```
$ sudo fsck.ext3 -fvy /dev/sdb2 && sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt && sudo tar xf rootfs_01.02.tar -C /mnt/ && sync && sleep 2 && sudo umount /dev/sdb2 && sleep 2 && sudo fsck.ext3 -fvy /dev/sdb2
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

        3388 inodes used (2.58%, out of 131072)
         208 non-contiguous files (6.1%)
           0 non-contiguous directories (0.0%)
             # of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 210/2/0
       56844 blocks used (10.84%, out of 524288)
           0 bad blocks
           1 large file

        2518 regular files
         323 directories
           0 character device files
           0 block device files
           0 fifos
          33 links
         538 symbolic links (538 fast symbolic links)
           0 sockets
------------
        3412 files
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.  Fix? yes

Inode 32964 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 65552 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

root: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****

        3388 inodes used (2.58%, out of 131072)
         213 non-contiguous files (6.3%)
           0 non-contiguous directories (0.0%)
             # of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 210/2/0
       56841 blocks used (10.84%, out of 524288)
           0 bad blocks
           1 large file

        2518 regular files
         323 directories
           0 character device files
           0 block device files
           0 fifos
          33 links
         538 symbolic links (538 fast symbolic links)
           0 sockets
------------
        3412 files
```

This happens consistently with several SDs, two different SD-card USB adapters and two PCs (same distribution).

Did anyone see something like this?

I cannot believe Linux SD handling is *so* buggy.

What should I check?

Comment: The problem is certainly not Linux SD handling. There is probably over a billion embedded systems running some linux on some kind of "SD card", usually eMMC, which is no card, but same interface and protocol, so for the kernel it's the same. On the other hand, consumer SDcards are not made to carry operation systems. To understand your specific problem we need to know what happens between initializing the file system and the problems found by `fsck`

Comment: @Philippos: If you look at the example output I posted in the question You will see I have a really strange behavior: fsck OK -> mount -> write -> umount -> fsck KO. This is on a PC (Intel i7-8770/KUbuntu) and not some random embedded HW. I am in the process to acquire another (micro)SD card reader (the two, somewhat old, ones I have seem to behave in the same, wrong, way). I concur Linux drivers, most likely, are *not* the culprit, but I cannot find a suitable candidate. SD cards are Transcend 8GB C10 HC

Comment: I'm sorry, indeed I overlooked that the fs was already ruined by unpacking entirely on the PC. In this case Linux never gets to know that there is an SDcard at all, because the MicroSD reader does the MMC communication, while being  USB mass storage to the PC. If this is reproducable for the MicroSdcard reader, yu could narrow down the problem by doing the same with a USB stick: For the Linux of the PC there is no difference about it. If it fails with a stick, the problem is on the PC side.

Comment: If it doesn't, you could try if it help to increase the sleep value: The `sync` only proves that the USB transmission is finished, be knows nothing about if the adapter is still writing to the card. And depending on the card and the adapter buffer, 2 s can be too short. After that, it will get difficult to debug.

Comment: I have now `... && umount /dev/sdb2 && sleep 15 && fsck.ext3 /dev/sdb2` and I have an even stranger behavior: apparently I get error at first round, but if I call the whole procedure again it completes without errors. This has happened several times now (on two different host with two different USB card readers).

Answer (score 0):

This happens on unclean removal or shutdown. I also suggest to use ext4.

Comment: How should I achieve "clean removal" if `sync && sleep 2 && sudo umount /dev/sdb2 && sleep 2` is not enough?